# Remove edits for deleted things from the review queue

Tags: bug, review

I got a weird edit review just now:

https://serverfault.com/review/suggested-edits/132341

It was for a dubious edit, so I clicked through to see if the editor's changes to the question were supported by some comment or something.  Then, I saw that the question was already deleted (https://serverfault.com/questions/607737/bashrc-not-loading-after-login).

It makes sense that the edit is still pending, but it seems kind of silly to have the review queue seek approval or denial of it when the question is gone.  Therefore I ask:

Do not include edits on deleted items (question or answer, moderator- or user-deleted) in the edit review queue.

The only reason such an edit would exist is if the question was deleted (by the user or a moderator, or automatically) after a user with low enough reputation to require edit approval (i.e. can't see deleted questions either) proposed an edit.

Comment: Deleted or not, this was an invalid edit suggestion, as it added information to the question.

Comment: Indeed it was, and I denied it, but reviewing these is still a waste of time notwithstanding that users over 10k can see them.  If the question was deleted by its owner, it seems unlikely editing will be any help.

Comment: Take a look at my answer, I gave a reason these edits may be useful, there.

Comment: However, if it was deleted by the question owner, I agree there's less of a point in keeping the edit, but I don't think corner cases like that warrant the removal of those suggested edits.

Comment: Not a removal of the suggested edit... just hiding it from the suggested edits queue.  It can go in the queue if the question is reopened.

Comment: This might be a better question for MSE or the Server Fault meta, considering this question is about content on a different site.

Comment: It should.  I thought I put it there... oops.

Comment: Why is that a server fault link?

Comment: It should be migrated there.

Answer (score 4):

Deleted or not, this was an invalid edit suggestion, as it added information to the question.

Deleted questions are still visible to a portion of the site's users.
As such, edit suggestions on deleted posts may prove useful, especially if they can clean up the answer enough to warrant a re-open vote.

There may be less reason to keep the suggested edit around if the OP deletes the question, himself. However, I've seen people delete their questions (and answers) while working on edits to the question. In that case, the suggested edit may still be valuable.

Comment: It'd be an undeletion vote.  I would agree with you more if deleted questions could be placed in the reopen review queue with an edit, but I don't believe that is the case - deletion is much stronger.

Comment: Users can always vote to un-delete, after their edits area accepted (Or after reviewing an edit on a deleted post)

Comment: If someone has to have their edit approved then they don't have undelete privs.

Comment: Hm, only after reviewing a edit where this applies, then.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I follow the rule that I consider edits that clearly don't improve a closed question enough to warrant opening (such as correcting typos) shouldn't be made, as this is only bumping a bad question.

If questions are voluntarily deleted, it would be more tricky to check whether the question can be un-deleted or not, but personally I'd disapprove of edits that don't fix the 'content' of the question significantly in this case. Not to blame the user of the edit, simple because I don't think this edit is worthwhile to have.