# What happens to a pending suggested edit when a post is deleted?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, deleted-posts

I just had a suggested edit on a post that was deleted before that edit could be approved or rejected. What happens to a suggested edit in that case? Does it get removed from the queue? Does it count as accepted/rejected/something else automatically?

I don't see this interaction listed on [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that/5222#5222)

And [Can a question or an answer be deleted when it has a pending revision?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100237/can-a-question-or-an-answer-be-deleted-when-it-has-a-pending-revision) comes very close to it (and is asked in a comment there) but never answers it.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235156/remove-edits-for-deleted-things-from-the-review-queue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I just had a suggested edit on a [post that was deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/337665/how-to-inform-a-user-about-wrong-editing-habits) before that edit could be approved or rejected. What happens to a suggested edit **in that case**?

It [sits in the queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/68612) for the next reviewer, and I approved it.

[image: Proof of my answer.]

> **[Where do suggested edits go?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/282094)**
>
> "Suggested edits are held in a peer review queue of a fixed size. If the queue fills up, no more edit suggestions will be allowed until the queue has some empty space."

Since you are under 2K reputation, see also:

> **[Can I earn reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/76284/282094)**
>
> "When a suggested edit is approved, **the user who suggested it gets +2 reputation**. The regular daily reputation cap applies, and the total cap for reputation gained via suggested edits is 1,000. **The +2 is reversed if the edited post is ever deleted** or if the final user to review one of your suggestions gets their account deleted.".

It's another approval to your credit, but no increase in reputation for your effort.

Comment: I generally reject suggested edit to deleted posts for the sole reason of them being deleted (which you can know beforehand by the lack of a "improve" or "reject and edit" button)

Comment: @pppery That puts someonen closer to a ban for no reason and after the edit the owner might decide to undelete the post. If subsequent reviewers vote against your rejection ***you*** are the one whom will receive increased Review Audits and the moderators can decide to manually ban you for such behaviour. Just because something is deleted or you have rejected something doesn't mean that the information isn't still available for others to see.

Answer (score 5):

I just did a test with this.

> What happens to a suggested edit in that case

It gets left in the review queue for the owner only and no-one else.

> Does it count as accepted/rejected/something else automatically?

No, the user can still approve/reject the edit, if approved the edit will still be made even if the post is deleted.

See image:

[image]

Comment: "It gets left in the review queue for the owner only and no-one else." How did you verify this? The other answer seems to contradict it.